# Dynamically set setEnabledProtocols other than SSLSocket.setEnabledProtocols

Tags: java, web-services, sockets, ssl, encryption

Hi do any one having idea about setting setEnabledProtocols other than java code

```
SSLSocket.setEnabledProtocols(newProtocol);
```

Because in our web service code we couldn't find any socket connection.

Thanks in advance. Appreciate your help if you guide me in setting dynamic UNIX java command.

Answer (score 0):

Like that:

```
    SSLContext context = SSLUtils.createSSLContext();

    // Connect to the tracer
    SSLSocketFactory factory = context.getSocketFactory();
    SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(endpointId.getHostName(), 
                        endpointId.getPort());
                
    // Enable TLS protocols
    SSLParameters params = new SSLParameters();
    params.setProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1", "TLSv1.1","TLSv1.2"});
    sslSocket.setSSLParameters(params);

    // Initialize the SSL handshake
    sslSocket.startHandshake();
```

Answer (score -1):

I have used System.setproperty("https.protocol","SSLv3"); and now its working fine.

Comment: You can't describe that as 'dynamic'.